# Why can't pervasives.cmi be opened?

Tags: ocaml

Installed Ocaml on my cygwin machine but simple compiles fail. Permissions are fine as you can see by the interaction below. OCAMLLIB is right; What is wrong?

```
$ cat t.ml

print_string "hi";

$ ocamlopt t.ml
>> Fatal error: cannot open pervasives.cmi
Fatal error: exception Misc.Fatal_error

$ echo $OCAMLLIB
/cygdrive/c/OCaml/lib

$ ls -l /cygdrive/c/OCaml/lib/pervasives.cmi
-rwxrwxrwx+ 1 Lyn None 15094 Oct  8 01:30 /cygdrive/c/OCaml/lib/pervasives.cmi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A possible solution is to run this command in cygwin:

```
export OCAMLLIB=C:\\OCaml\\lib
```

The clue came from this [message thread](http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/frama-c-discuss/2009-December/001653.html).

Comment: yes indeed it runs fine under a cmd shell, but this is the cygwin version of ocaml from here: http://protz.github.com/ocaml-installer/

Comment: I found this [message thread](http://lists.gforge.inria.fr/pipermail/frama-c-discuss/2009-December/001653.html) that might have a useful tip regarding how to setup the OCAMLLIB environment var.

Comment: Brilliant! Put this in your answer and I'll accept: export OCAMLLIB=C:\\OCaml\\lib

Comment: I recently had a similar issue as well, https://github.com/protz/ocaml-installer/issues/21

Comment: Was there anything else you did to make it work? Adding that didn't solve my issue.