# tuareg mode emacs ocaml not found

Tags: macos, emacs, ocaml, tuareg

I am running emacs 24.3 on mac os x 10.9. I have installed the tuareg-mode for ocaml programming but am unable to compile using the command C-c C-b. On pressing the same, the minibuffer asks me about 'Caml toplevel to run: ocaml'. When I press enter it shows the error "Searching for program: No such file or directory, ocaml". What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found this cool mode that autoloads the shell variables into emacs environment for mac users. Very handy:

https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell

Just install it and update your .emacs file and you are set.

Comment: Helped me, but when installing it from ELPA I had to add `(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'exec-path-from-shell-initialize)` to my init file instead of what the docs were saying.

Answer (score 1):

you need to setup `PATH` environment variable & the Emacs's `exec-path` variable to correct values.  One possibility is to use something like (in your `~/.emacs`):

```
(defun set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH ()
  (let ((path-from-shell (shell-command-to-string "$SHELL -c 'echo $PATH'")))
    (setenv "PATH" path-from-shell)
    (setq exec-path (split-string path-from-shell path-separator))))
(when window-system (set-exec-path-from-shell-PATH))
```

to get the `PATH` from shell and both variables correctly.  One advantage of this is that you will setup `PATH` only in one place - in your shell init script.

Comment: So I understood the part about setting path variable in my emacs shell but wasn't the path already set in my shell init script when I installed ocaml. Why do I have to set it again. And pardon my ignorance.

Comment: When Emacs is started it's started from "initial" process, that doesn't have your PATH customizations - you can check this by executing the `M-x getenv PATH` and `C-h v exec-path` (before execution of my snippet of code) and comparing values with your actual shell output of `echo $PATH` ...

Comment: That appears to have worked but now I have stumbled upon another problem. The error I get now is : "Fatal error: cannot open implicit module "Pervasives"
Fatal error: exception Misc.Fatal_error". Apparently ocaml only runs under admin privileges in my bash shell. How can I achieve it from emacs!

Comment: I think, that it's something wrong with OCaml installation - how have you installed it? You can also look to following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712618/why-cant-pervasives-cmi-be-opened

Comment: I downlaoded ocaml-4.01.dmg from the official website and installed it from there.

Comment: have you tried to set the `OCAMLLIB` environment variable as was pointed in the answer to question?