# Fatal error in ocaml-top level

Tags: emacs, ocaml, fatal-error

Currently I'm using OCaml 4.01.0. The compiler [ocaml-top](http://www.typerex.org/)  ran well for the first time i installed. For few hours ago, i wrote a code which take an input from standard input, it crashed. I don't understand why but I checked with the compiler online, it worked fine!

And now when I open the compiler, an error appear:

```
Fatal error: cannot open implicit module "Pervasives"

Fatal error: exception Misc.Fatal_error
```

I also checked with emacs by typing:

```
Alt + x

run-caml

<press Enter>
```

still doesn't work! The error still appears. Could someone please help me to fix this? I'm a beginner in OCaml, I just started for few days.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Are you on Cygwin? If so, this is possibly a duplicate of [Why can't pervasives.cmi be opened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15712618/why-cant-pervasives-cmi-be-opened).

Comment: I did it ... but still wasn't successful

Answer (score 0):

I am using Eclipse, and I just solved the same problem- In Windows--> Preferences (or Mac's Eclipse --> Preference), go to OcalDE and its path.  Make sure that you have the right paths.  I forgot to put in my library path and that was why I had this problem.  Hope this helps :p